# Does the order of generating functions imply the order of coefficients?

Tags: real-analysis, generating-functions

Suppose that we have two generating functions $f(z)=\sum_{n \ge 0} f_n z^n$ and $g(z)=\sum_{n \ge 0} g_n z^n$ with non-negative coefficients. Assume that the radius of convergence is $\infty$ for both functions and that
$$
f(z) \le g(z)
$$
for all $z \ge 0$. Then, do we have $f_n \le g_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$?

---

I realized, this it to ask if $f(z)=\sum_{n \ge 0} f_n z^n \ge 0$ on $[0,\infty)$ implies all coefficients are non-negative. I.e., does non-negativity of generating function implies non-negativity of coefficients?

Comment: No certainly not.  $1+\cos(x)$ is everywhere nonnegative, but has many negative Maclaurin coefficients.

Comment: This is not true. Consider the counterexample$$f(z)=z\qquad g(z)=1+z^2$$

Comment: For your second point note that clearly$$(1-z)^2=1-2z+z^2$$is non-negative but has negative coefficients.